# Scala reflection - why TypeTag and Type?

Tags: scala, reflection

These two types/classes in the Scala reflection API seem to represent the same thing. Why are they two separate types?

`scala.reflect.api.Universe.Type`
`scala.reflect.api.Universe.TypeTag`

Link to scala docs: [scala.reflect.api.Universe](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Universe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Type` is a reflection artifact bound to a particular universe. `TypeTag` is a type factory, capable of instantiating a type in any universe.